# Weird limit with/without derivation

Tags: limits

I have no idea how can I solve the following:

> $$ x^2\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x}-e\,x^{3}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

with $x$ tends to infinity. Thank you.

Comment: Does $lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x}$ remember you something?

Comment: yes,sure, but wolfram gives me e/8 as final result

Comment: And Wolfram is right.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you like this or not. Noting
$$ e^t=1+t+\frac12t^2+O(t^3),\ln(1+t)=t-\frac{t^2}2+\frac{t^3}3+O(t^4). $$
Letting $t=\frac1x$ one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&x^2(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x}-ex^{3}\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})\\
&=&\frac1{t^2}e^{\frac{\ln(1+t)}t}-\frac{e}{t^3}\ln(1+t)\\
&=&\frac1{t^2}e^{1-\frac12t+\frac13t^2+O(t^3)}-\frac{e}{t^3}\bigg(t-\frac{t^2}2+\frac{t^3}3+O(t^4)\bigg)\\
&=&\frac e{t^2}e^{-\frac12t+\frac13t^2+O(t^3)}-\frac{e}{t^3}\bigg(t-\frac{t^2}2+\frac{t^3}3+O(t^4)\bigg)\\
&=&\frac e{t^2}\bigg(1+(-\frac12t+\frac13t^2+O(t^3))+\frac12(-\frac12t+\frac13t^2+O(t^3))^2+O(t^3)\bigg)-\frac{e}{t^3}\bigg(t-\frac{t^2}2+\frac{t^3}3+O(t^4)\bigg)\\
&=&\frac e8+O(t)
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\bigg[x^2(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x}-ex^{3}\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})\bigg]=\frac e8. $$

Answer (score 0):

We could go beyound the limit itself and get the asymptotics composing Taylor series one piece at the time.
$$y=x^2\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x}-e\,x^{3}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

$$a=\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x}\implies \log(a)=x \log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
$$\log(a)=x \left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2 x^2}+\frac{1}{3
   x^3}-\frac{1}{4
   x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right) \right)$$

$$\log(a)=1-\frac{1}{2 x}+\frac{1}{3 x^2}-\frac{1}{4
   x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$$
$$a=e^{\log(a)}=e-\frac{e}{2 x}+\frac{11 e}{24 x^2}-\frac{7e}{16
   x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$$ Back to $y$
$$y=x^2\left(e-\frac{e}{2 x}+\frac{11 e}{24 x^2}-\frac{7e}{16
   x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right) \right)-
 e x^3\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2 x^2}+\frac{1}{3
   x^3}-\frac{1}{4
   x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right) \right)$$

$$y=\frac{e}{8}-\frac{3 e}{16 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) $$